# Не переведен текст в "Основах форматирования"

Tags: дефект, локализация, форматирование

На [странице создания нового вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) если поместить курсор в поле **Основная часть**, то справа появляется блок **Основы форматирования**, в нем часть пунктов не переведена на русский язык:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И в справке по markdown на вкладке "Код" тоже.

Comment: О! Полезная фича - почему я не знал? ((

Comment: ru.traducir.win

Comment: @Qwertiy потому, что это появилось только в январе: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322000/370389

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перевод выполнен:

> [image: основы форматирования]